# Trigger OnSave [Visual studio code: Extension]

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm a bit stuck on creating a visual studio code Extension. It works when I manually trigger it using the command, but I like to trigger it on save. Or maybe on a custom hot-key?

I've been searching for a while now, but the documentation is a bit vague on the subject. Been trying to understand other plugins but I have not found the answer yet.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to trigger an action when a document is saved? Do it like this:

```
workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((document: TextDocument) => {
    if (document.languageId === "yourid" && document.uri.scheme === "file") {
        // do work
    }
});
```

Watch out: check the document URI scheme to avoid acting on other resources beside files (e.g. github links).

Comment: Ahh! It's under workspace. Was searching under window. I'm going to try this out! Thank you! Other question, it's the only difference between user and workspace is that workspace can be shared easily?

Comment: When you find my answer working for you please accept it and maybe even upvote, if you think it's worth it. For the other question, start a fresh question on SO.